# R Shiny : Different type of output based on reactive value

Tags: r, shiny, conditional-statements, render, networkd3

I tried to display a Radial Network or a Diagonal Network (using package [networkD3](https://christophergandrud.github.io/networkD3/)) according to the value of a the radio buttons input `param_type_graph`. I tried to put some if statement in my renderUI() function, but obviously it does not work. The Shiny App is [there](https://snak.shinyapps.io/carrefour_explo_hh/). It only works for the radial case. Please test the app with the following input: *1st input*: "**petrus**"; *2nd input*: '**WinesAndCo**', and then submit by clicking on the last blue button.

**UI**

```
ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Carrefour Hierarchical Exploration"),

  sidebarLayout(

    # Sidebar with a slider input
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("param_caption", "Rechercher une famille de vin : ", "petrus"),
      radioButtons("param_sites", "Choisis sur quel site",
                   c("Auchan" = "1",
                     "G.V.P." = "2",
                     "Lavinia" = "3",
                     "Millesima" = "4",
                     "Vinatis"="5",
                     "WinesAndCo"="6")),
      radioButtons("param_typegraph", "Type de Graphique",
                   c("Radial Network" = "rad",
                     "Diagonal Network" = "diag"
                     )),
      sliderInput("param_height", "Graph Height:",
                  min = 300, max = 3000, value = 300
      ),
      sliderInput("param_width", "Graph Width:",
                  min = 400, max = 4000, value = 400
      ),
      sliderInput("param_size", "Police Size:",
                  min = 10, max = 60, value = 10
      ),
      actionButton(inputId="param_go",label="Submit",style="color: #fff; background-color: #337ab7; border-color: #2e6da4")


    ),
    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput('mygraph')

    )
  )
)
```

**SERVER**

```
server <- function(input, output) {
# a lot of compution ... that I do not display
# ...
  output$graphresdiag <- renderDiagonalNetwork({
    diagonalNetwork (tree_to_display(),height = input$param_height,width = input$param_width, fontSize = input$param_size)
  })
  output$graphresrad <- renderRadialNetwork({
    radialNetwork (tree_to_display(),height = input$param_height,width = input$param_width, fontSize = input$param_size)
  })

  output$mygraph= renderUI({

    if (isolate(input$param_typegraph)=="diag")
        {diagonalNetworkOutput(outputId = "graphresdiag",
                                width = paste0(input$param_width,"px"),
                                height =paste0(input$param_height,"px") )}

    if (isolate(input$param_typegraph)=="rad")
    {radialNetworkOutput(outputId = "graphresrad",
                           width = paste0(input$param_width,"px"),
                           height =paste0(input$param_height,"px") )}


  })

}
```

What would you do to make it work?

Comment: Try `conditionalPanel`

Comment: thks it seems it's what I look for

Answer (score 1):

ok guys I did it. Below part of codes that I modified to make it work.

**UI**

```
mainPanel(

  conditionalPanel(
    condition = "input.param_typegraph == 'rad'",
    uiOutput('mytabs')
  ),
  conditionalPanel(
    condition = "input.param_typegraph == 'diag'",
    uiOutput('mytabsii')
  )

)
```

**SERVER**

```
  output$graphresdiag <- renderDiagonalNetwork({
    diagonalNetwork (tree_to_display(),height = input$param_height,width = input$param_width, fontSize = input$param_size)
  })
  output$graphresrad <- renderRadialNetwork({
    radialNetwork (tree_to_display(),height = input$param_height,width = input$param_width, fontSize = input$param_size)
  })

  output$mytabs = renderUI({

radialNetworkOutput(outputId = "graphresrad",
                           width = paste0(input$param_width,"px"),
                           height =paste0(input$param_height,"px") )

  })


  output$mytabsii = renderUI({

    diagonalNetworkOutput(outputId = "graphresdiag",
                          width = paste0(input$param_width,"px"),
                          height =paste0(input$param_height,"px") )

  })
```

Answer (score 1):

I am adding this answer for future readers.

I was using NetworkD3 package and was trying to do something similar and realized your code can be simplified this way:

**UI**

```
mainPanel(
conditionalPanel(
    condition = "input.param_typegraph == 'rad'",
    radialNetworkOutput('mytabs')
),
conditionalPanel(
    condition = "input.param_typegraph == 'diag'",
    diagonalNetworkOutput('mytabsii')
)
)
```

**SERVER**

```
output$mytabs <- renderDiagonalNetwork({
    diagonalNetwork (tree_to_display(), height = input$param_height, width = input$param_width, fontSize = input$param_size)
})
output$mytabsii <- renderRadialNetwork({
radialNetwork (tree_to_display(), height = input$param_height, width = input$param_width, fontSize = input$param_size)
})

})
```

Basically you did like this:

> UI: conditionalPanel <- uiOutput(x)
>
> SERVER: output$x <- renderUI <- yOutput(z) <- output$z <- renderY

This can be simplified as:

> UI: conditionalPanel <- yOutput(x)
>
> SERVER: output$x <- renderY

Hope it helps someone.